# Excel VBA Sheet.Copy doesn't keep ActiveX Objects

Tags: vba, excel, activex, activexobject

this is question maybe not regarding to coding itself, maybe it is question about "Do you observed that problem?"

In Excel I have template sheet with name "Template". This sheet contains row of ActiveX objects (images, which are used as buttons). 
I also have second sheet let's call it "Setup" which creates copy of "Tepmlate" sheet when "Generate" button is clicked.

```
Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

On European computers it works as expected, also in India, but on most of USA workstations copied Sheet doesn't contains ActiveX objects.

Do you have any idea, what can cause this situation? I'm sitting in EU, what to check on USA computers? They have same combination of OS/MS Office. I tried almost any trust center settings in Excel which results maximaly in unclickable buttons but I'm not able to simulate situation, when Sheet is coppied without ActiveX objects.

Comment: Are you able to confirm if this behavior occurs when the VB editor is explicitly opened, before you run the code? Does it occur if the sheet is activated (in code) before being copied?

Comment: [READ THIS](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/how-to-copy-an-active-x-control-to-other-sheets-in/83cc050d-cf1f-4619-acb4-6d5a2890e2e1?auth=1) . Hope this helps. (Sorry for the CAPS)

Comment: Have you tried opening it in safe mode? Hold Ctrl down as you click the Excel shortcut, then confirm safe mode when prompted.

Comment: How about creating a template workbook and then use that to create a new workbook? rather then a template sheet (which isn't a true template)

Comment: Does the code behind of the controls contain characters not in the first 127 points of the ANSI codepage on your system? I am not sure this could cause this particular problem but it is generally problematic for international use.